# Testing Facebook Share Dialog with localhost - "Unable to resolve object at URL http://localhost"

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to use the current (at date of asking this question) Facebook Share Dialog using just the URL (not the SDK).

My JS looks like this:

```
openFacebookPopup : function (url) {
        this.openSharerWindow('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share' + '?app_id=145634995501895' + '&display=popup' + '&href=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost' + '&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost');
        return false;
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Could not resolve object at URL `http://localhost/`.

What does that mean and how do I go about trying to resolve it?
I should note that this JS does work without problems using the old 'sharer.php' url for facebook.

I've got `http://localhost` added into my app.

Comment: It means that Facebook can not scrape your site

Comment: Ok. What does Facebook not being able to scrape my site mean?

Comment: Facebook need to be able to fetch the page you want to share to be able to get the information about it

Comment: Do you have any more information, like what the solution may be or how to begin going about fixing it?

Comment: Stop using localhost and use something Facebook can reach

Comment: Sorry I may not have made this clear, but the whole point of the question is that I want to be able to test the Facebook Share Dialog in my local environment.

Comment: And I just tried to explain that it will not work

Comment: WizKid, your answers didn't help anyone.

Comment: @davidpauljunior: Hey are you able to find a solution. I am also stuck here.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Inquisitive I'm afraid not.  I haven't investigated the answer below from maxhs yet - I ran out of time on my project.  I plan to reinvestigate soon!

Answer (score 8):

Since FB can't access to your localhost to feed the popup, you have to feed it yourself.

First, add the Facebook's Javascript SDK on every pages you need it :

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'your-app-id',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.3'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Then, bind this function on whatever trigger you want, a click event for example :

```
$('#fb-share-button').click(function() {
    FB.ui({
          method: 'feed',
          link: "The link you want to share", 
          picture: 'The picture url',
          name: "The name who will be displayed on the post",
          description: "The description who will be displayed"
        }, function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    );
});
```

I console.log the response but in this block you can do what you want. Catch the response to see if the post has been well shared for example.

Answer (score 5):

What @WizKid is trying to say is that Facebook is looking for some meta tags on your page (e.g. `<meta property="og:title" content="My awesome site" />`, so that it can structure the content of your share... but isn't finding them. Your current share may work on production, but won't on localhost. You can test to see what facebook is looking for with their url debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

The old URL-parameter-based sharing works with localhost (if you've added it as a site URL and app domain) because all facebook had to do in that instance was parse the query parameters of your share string.

Answer (score 0):

To test facebook share debugger on localhost we can create a tunnel.

Follow the below steps
[image: follow the steps]
source: [facebook share debugger on localhost](https://samvikshana.weebly.com/blog/how-to-use-facebook-sharing-debugger-and-twitter-card-validator-with-localhost-urls)